# How to improve performance for ionic app with items > 100000?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an app built in ionic 4 in which we have a page where we display all the available items. This item can be range from 0 to 1,00,000. Currently when the list is loaded the app performance goes down by which the app closes unexepectedly.

So I am looking for a solution that can help me to improve the performance of the item loading and rendering.

Comment: do not load all items one time, load first 100 for example, load more while user action or necessary.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're kiling the app yourself by doing that. What is your backend? Try pagination and infinite-scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try using a virtual scroll.

There's a tutorial just here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgPNdoB1zhk&ab_channel=SimonGrimm

The HTTP request will still get 100 000 items, but you will display just a part of it into your template.

Another way to display it without burning your PC is to use a simple pagination.

Comment: The link's probably already referring to it (or a similar version thereof) but Ionic's `ion-infinite-scroll` sounds like the ideal solution. See https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll

Answer (score 0):

If the "app closes unexepectedly", then you need to investigate where the app is crashing. Does the app crash when you request data from the server or after data has been fetched and needs to be displayed on page.